# Why does AR(P) = MA(P)

Tags: time-series

I am working my way through lecture notes from an econometrics course taught at Ohio State University on time series analysis. The current set of notes I am on (https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/de-jong.8/note2.pdf) discusses ARMA models.

On page 2 the notes introduce the lag operator ($ Lx_t = x_{t-1}; L^{k}x_{t} = x_{t-k}$) and then gives the following definitions:

let

$$\epsilon_t = WN(0,\sigma^{2})$$

$$
\phi(L) = 1 - \phi_{1}L - \phi_{2}L^{2} - ... - \phi_{p}L^{p}
$$

$$
\theta(L) = 1 + \theta_{1}L + \theta_{2}L^{2}...+\theta_{p}L^{q}
$$

AR : $\phi(L)x_{t} = \epsilon_{t}$

MA : $x_{t} = \theta(L)\epsilon_{t}$

ARMA : $\phi(L)x_{t} = \theta(L)\epsilon_{t}$

I cannot see why the final expression follows, unless $x_{t} = 0$. An ARMA model is $x_{t} = AR(p) + MA(p)$. The terms in the above AR definition are negative, so adding AR to both sides would give $x_{t} + AR(P) = MA(P)$,  but that isn't what the notes say. Can anyone with a bigger brain than me (plenty of you in here!) explain what I've missed?

Comment: Hi: It's not meant to be an an algebraic equivalence. All that is saying is that one can have an AR model or an MA model or a combination of both which is ARMA.  Usually people use ARMA because the AR or MA alone will often need a lot of coefficients. By using an ARMA, the amount of coefficients needed is often less than when using AR or MA alone.  There are reasons why this is the case but it's too long to go into here. There is a ton of literature on the "Box-Jenkins" approach on the net and in textbooks. Hamilton's "Time Series Analysis" is decent for ARMA.

Comment: Thank you! That's helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an answer to this question, but since I also had trouble understanding AR, MA, and ARMA models when I first learned about them, I want to share what helped me understand the models better:

Consider the equation $$\Psi(L)x_t = \Xi(L)\epsilon_t,$$ where $\Psi$ and $\Xi$ are functions of the linear operator $L : S^T\rightarrow S^T$ with $S^T$ denoting the set of all functions $T\rightarrow S$. Typical choices are $T = \mathbb N$ and $S = \mathbb R$, or $S = \mathbb R^d$.

Now $\Psi$ and $\Xi$ are functions of $L$. Let's consider some particular choices for $\Psi$ and $\Xi$:

- Let $\Psi = 1$ and $\Xi = 1$, where $1$ is not the number 1, but the identity operator, i. e. $1(L) = L$. The resulting equation is $$x_t = \epsilon_t.$$ This model is (trivially) white noise.
- Let $\Psi = \phi$ and $\Xi = 1$, where $\phi$ is some polynomial of degree $p$, i. e. $\phi(L) = 1 - \phi_1 L - \phi_2 L^2 - \dots - \phi_p L^p$. Note that $1$ corresponds again to the identity operator and not the number. The resulting equation is $$x_t - \phi_1 x_{t-1} - \phi_2 x_{t-2} - \dots - \phi_p x_{t-p} = \epsilon_t.$$ This model is called AR process.
- Let $\Psi = 1$ and $\Xi = \theta$, where $\theta$ is some polynomial of degree $q$, i. e. $\theta(L) = 1 + \theta_0 L + \theta_2 L^2 + \dots + \theta_q L^q$. Note that $1$ corresponds again to the identity operator and not the number. The resulting equation is $$x_t = \theta_0\epsilon_t + \theta_1\epsilon_{t-1} + \theta_2\epsilon_{t-2} + \dots + \theta_q\epsilon_{t-q}.$$ This model is called MA process.
- Let $\Psi = \phi$ and $\Xi = \theta$, where $\theta$ and $\phi$ are defined as before. The resulting equation is $$x_t - \phi_1 x_{t-1} - \phi_2 x_{t-2} - \dots - \phi_p x_{t-p} = \epsilon_t + \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t-2} + \dots + \epsilon_{t-q}.$$ This process is called ARMA process, because it combined both AR and MA process.

There are, of course, other possible choices for $\Psi$ and $\Xi$, e. g. the [operator exponential](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/voices.uchicago.edu/dist/0/1830/files/2019/07/Exponential-Operators.pdf) $\operatorname{Exp}$, an affine shift, a scaling, ...

However, the polynomial functions have some handy properties and thus are particularly interesting to study.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you here. ARMA representation does not come from adding AR and MA. AR stands for autoregression, and MA stands for moving average. So ARMA is simply having both the 'AR' feature $\phi(L)x_t$ and the 'MA' feature $\theta(L)\epsilon_t$. Also there's a constant 1 in both polynomials, so adding $x_t$ again would not make much sense.

Comment: Indeed! This is partly the source of my confusion. Although the combination of AR and MA that goes into ARMA gives $x_t = \phi x{t-1} + \epsilon_{t} + \theta_{1} \epsilon_{t-1}$ etc, so one could forgiven for thinking they're added together!

Comment: @Quertiopler: That was a nice explanation. It's not that big of a deal ( as long as the person who asked notices the typo ) but you forgot to put $\theta$ coefficients on the $\epsilon$ when you wrote out the MA model.